# Illegal instance declaration

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I just created a class with Haskell but I have a problem with one of my instances. I've created this class:

```hs
class Symbol a where
  nameSym :: a -> String
```

and these instances:

```hs
instance Symbol Double where
  nameSym db = show db 

instance Symbol String where
  nameSym str = str
```

but when compiling, I get the following error message:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Symbol String'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
   where T is not a synonym.
In the instance declaration for `Symbol String'
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: String is a type synonym, you can use [Char] or some compiler option that allows type synonyms in instances.

Comment: Enable `FlexibleInstances` as GHC should suggest. That extension is harmless and has been in use by many libraries since a long time.

Comment: `[Char]` is also not a valid instance head under the default rules - you'll still need `FlexibleInstances`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pragma :

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

at the head of your source file.

Comment: This answer provides a solution, but can you explain the source of the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `String` is a type alias for `[Char]` and the Haskell 98 specification does not allow for instances to be defined on type aliases. That can be solved by adding this in the header of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
```

However, that still won't allow you to compile the program as Haskell 98 also doesn't allow instances for `[SomeConcreteType]` (only instances for `[a]` are allowed — thanks to Ørjan for pointing that one out), and whereas there exists a workaround for that in Haskell 98 without the use of language pragmas, the easiest way to solve this one (and it's also completely safe and idiomatic) is to add the following pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

— this also enables `TypeSynonymInstances` so you don't need to keep both pragmas.

Comment: Haskell 98 and also Haskell 2010 do allow instances for `[a]`. It's just that the `a` actually has to be a type variable.